# How I load a script from assets to Angular2 project?

Tags: angular

I would like to import a script from `assets`. I do this at `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>...</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--npm package : image-compressor-->
  <script src="/assets/image-compressor/image-compressor.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    Loading...
  </app-root>
</body>
```

and in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = '...';
  ngOnInit(){
    var imageCompressor = new ImageCompressor(); //create a ImageCompressor from image-compreeor package
    console.log(imageCompressor)
    ...
  }
}
```

then I got a error which has been throw at running, although the error, the website still run and show the ImageCompressor which got on `app.component.ts`.
when I build project `ng build` will be got same error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(??,31): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'ImageCompressor'. Did you mean 'imageCompressor'?
```

How could I do?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you include some `import { ImageCompressor } from 'pathToYourAsset';` ?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes, @Talavera.

Comment: Then in your angular-cli.json you should have an "scripts" property, add there the path to the assets file you want to include (e.g. "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ] )

Answer (score 0):

The way you added the image-compressor.js file, it unknown to the compiler

Try adding

```
declare var ImageCompressor: any;
```

before declaring your component in app.component.ts